# Customise Win10 Start Menu on Domain

Tags: windows, windows-10

Currently we are in the process of deploying Win10 across our main office and 2 satelite offices. We want to customise the start menu with our standard office packages as tiles as well as allow the users to customise the start menu with their own tiles.

I have seen you can modify the start menu, export and push that with group policy. This is simply done by doing the following steps detailed below. However, this method prevents out users adding their own tiles or laying it out as they want it. The network manager doesn't want to totally lock it down. He wants to allow some flexibillity for users to make it their own. Is there any way this can be acheived?

**GP METHOD**

- Create a custom layout with the tiles
  [image]
- Go to powershell and use the command

> Export-StartLayout -Path C:\Temp\LayoutMod.xml

- Copy this file to the domain controller or shared a shared file on a server.
- In group policy editor, expand user configuration -> go to administrative templates and click start menu and taskbar.
- Double Click the start meny layout poilicy.
- Enable and point to the location the XML is stored on the server. 
  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by performing the customization you'd like on a dummy account, just as you do in the Group Policy method; you would also still export the `XML` file with the following PowerShell:

`Export-StartLayout -Path C:\LayoutModification.xml`

However, instead of enforcing it with Group Policy you copy the file to `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`

This will make it so that any new user logging on to the system inherits these settings, yet can still customize them.

Since I provision with Configuration Manager, I use the following along with a Software Package in a Task Sequence to copy the file:

```
Copy-Item "LayoutModification.xml" `
 -Destination "$env:SystemDrive\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell"
```

[Reference](https://adminfix.wordpress.com/2015/10/28/windows-10-start-menu-customization/)

Comment: Excellent thats what we need. So any new users that login to a machine inherit our designed start menu. How would we push that out to users who are already using windows 10 so won't inherit it when they logon.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd be able to control that, or at least I wouldn't know how.  Plus you'd be overwriting any modifications they've made since, which I'm not sure you'd want to do.  The method I posted is really good for when you're creating your base-load or image.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes majority of the ysers leave it as standard for the reason they dont understand it. So overwriting it wouldn't be a problem. 

Thanks for your help though Josh.